# Sharepoint Client in C# Share a folder with specific user

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We have a .NET web application that upload file to SharePoint using SharePoint.Client. The site connect to SharePoint using APP client ID and secret. The folder creation and file upload all work find. But it needs to share the folder (with subfolder where the document resides) with specific user in our organization, as it is done in SharePoint (see screenshot)

[Share folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7CYX.png)

[with specific user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4IsN.jpg)

I have tried many ways but mainly these two:

1. Through role binding: [Share specific folder in document library using SharePoint Client Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551858/share-specific-folder-in-document-library-using-sharepoint-client-object-model). But this gave me "Access Denied"
2. Through "SP.Web.ShareObject", passing similar parameters as in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279451/sharepoint-rest-api-shareobject-method . But the "SharingResult" it returns gave error "caller has no permission to grant permission".

Is there a way to accomplish this task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void sendEmailWithLink(string email, string role = "read")
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(contextoURL);
        SecureString passWordSegur = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in pw)
            passWordSegur.AppendChar(c);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, passWordSegur);

        Web web = context.Web;

        string aux = "[{\"Key\":\"" + email + "\"}]";
        string usuario = aux;

        if (role == "contribute")
        {
            SharingResult result = Web.ShareObject((ClientRuntimeContext)context, folderPath, usuario, "role:1073741827", 0, true, true, false, "Carpeta o documento de SharePoint compartido contigo", "", true);
            web.Context.Load(result);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        else if (role == "full control")
        {
            SharingResult result = Web.ShareObject((ClientRuntimeContext)context, folderPath, usuario, "role:1073741829", 0, true, true, false, "Carpeta o documento de SharePoint compartido contigo", "", true);
            web.Context.Load(result);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        else if (role == "edit")
        {
            SharingResult result = Web.ShareObject((ClientRuntimeContext)context, folderPath, usuario, "role:1073741830", 0, true, true, false, "Carpeta o documento de SharePoint compartido contigo", "", true);
            web.Context.Load(result);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        else if (role == "read")
        {
            SharingResult result = Web.ShareObject((ClientRuntimeContext)context, folderPath, usuario, "role:1073741826", 0, true, true, false, "Carpeta o documento de SharePoint compartido contigo", "a", true);
            web.Context.Load(result);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

This code sends an email to the email adress specified in "email" which contains a link that gives permision to some folder (specified in the folder path).

For the documentation about the ShareObject function check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/blogs/vesku/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business

About the aux usage is because your supposed to create a PersonPicker (in the link I share you can see all the information) but this just happens to work fine with me.